# Random forest regression scikit learn and feature importances

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to perform a regression for the first time, having always previously done classification.  I feel however that I am getting something basic wrong. My code snippet is:

```
vectorizer = DV( sparse = False )
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(cat_dict )
print len(X)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,  max_depth=None,min_samples_split=1, random_state=0)
reg.fit(X,Y)
scores = cross_val_score(reg, X, Y)
print scores
reg.fit(X,Y)
importances = reg.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    if importances[indices[f]] > 0:
        print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))
        print ("feature name: ", feature_names[indices[f]])
```

My questions are :

- The scores I get from `print scores` are `[-0.21087993 -0.60910592 -0.33646844]`. My guess is that these scores are the "the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction" but how do I interpret them? In particular, what is this telling me about the accuracy of the predictions?
- Is this really the best way to find out which features are most important?  My code is only showing features for a regressor which is fitted on the whole training+test data set which presumably overfits and is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Any answer to this? I'm having the same question now